# iOS 10.3 support in the app which is built using Cordova iOS 6.0.0

Tags: ios, cordova, xcode11

I have a web app created in ReactJS, and I have built its native Android and iOS apps using Cordova. After the release of Cordova iOS 6.0.0 to support WKWebView after UIWebView got deprecated, it stopped supporting iOS version 10.3.
How can I get the support for iOS 10.3 using Cordova iOS 6.0.0? Or is there an alternative?

When I selected the target as iOS 10.3 in Xcode, then the build gets failed but when I change the target to iOS 11.0, then the build is successful and working as expected.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide the pieces of code that stopped working. Other users with knowledge of Cordova can then have a look and might help you out.

Comment: @KevinVugts Build itself getting failed when I selected the target as iOS 10.3 in Xcode. When I change the target to iOS 11.0, the build is successful and working as expected.